# Why function variable changes after I call the function second times in Python?

Tags: python, function, variable-assignment, user-defined-functions

I am trying to define Cost function for neural network. I call the function from main as described below:

```
#without regularization
lambda_rate = 0
J,Theta_1,Theta_2 = functions.nnCostFunction(initial_theta1,initial_theta2,input_layer_size,hidden_layer_size,num_labels,X, y, lambda_rate,m)

#testing regularization
lambda_rate = 1
J,Theta_1,Theta_2 = functions.nnCostFunction(initial_theta1,initial_theta2,input_layer_size,hidden_layer_size,num_labels,X, y, lambda_rate,m)
```

And the function itself as described below but the problem is when I set the theta arrays's first column to zero, of course theta arrays are changing. I am doing this section at the end of the function so there is no need to care about theta change in my opinion. As I change the theta1 and theta2, when I recall the function to test the regularization part, theta1 and theta2 comes with previous changed values even I assign them to initial_theta values at the beginning of function.

I think I understand the problem which could be: I reference the theta1 and theta2 to initial_theta values. As I referenced, when I change the theta1 it changes the initial_theta. But even those are all happening, I am going back to main so why it happens when I recall the function? Is that problem causes because I define initial_theta1 and initial_theta2 as same name in the main?

```
 def nnCostFunction(initial_theta1,initial_theta2,input_layer_size,hidden_layer_size,num_labels,X, y, lambda_rate,m):
        J = 0
        X = np.insert(X,0,1.0,axis=1) #adding bias to input layer
        v = np.zeros((m,num_labels)) #create zeros for output unit as 10 class classification
        Theta1 = initial_theta1
        Theta2 = initial_theta2
        for i in range(m):         #define output units variable
            v[i][(y[i])-1] = 1

        z2 = np.matmul(X,Theta1.transpose())
        a2 = sigmoid(z2)
        a2 = np.insert(a2,0,1.0,axis=1)
        z3 = np.matmul(a2,Theta2.transpose())
        a3 = sigmoid(z3)
        #Non-Regularized Cost
        for i in range(num_labels):
            J_test = (1/m)*(np.matmul(-v[:,i].transpose(),np.log(a3)[:,i])-np.matmul(1-v[:,i].transpose(),np.log(1-a3)[:,i]))
            J = J+J_test
        #Regularized Cost    
        Regular_part = (lambda_rate/(2*m))*(sum(sum(np.power(Theta1[:,1:],2)))+sum(sum(np.power(Theta2[:,1:],2))))
        J = J+Regular_part

        #Back Propagation
        der_error_3 = (a3 - y)
        der_error_2 = np.multiply(np.matmul(der_error_3,Theta2[:,1:]),sigmoid_prime(z2))

        delta_2 = np.matmul(der_error_3.transpose(),a2)
        delta_1 = np.matmul(der_error_2.transpose(),X)

        Theta1[:,0] = 0 #setting first column of theta1 to zeros for regularization of backpropagation algorithm
        Theta2[:,0] = 0 #setting first column of theta2 to zeros for regularization of backpropagation algorithm

        Theta1 = Theta1*lambda_rate/m;
        Theta2 = Theta2*lambda_rate/m;
        Theta1_grad = delta_1/m+Theta1;
        Theta2_grad = delta_2/m+Theta2; 

        return J,Theta1_grad,Theta2_grad
```

One possible solution to that problem is writing a code as below.

```
      Theta1_Reg,Theta2_Reg = Theta1.copy(),Theta2.copy()
      Theta1_Reg[:,0] = 0     #setting first column of theta1 to zeros for regularization of backpropagation algorithm
      Theta2_Reg[:,0] = 0     #setting first column of theta2 to zeros for regularization of backpropagation algorithm
```

or at the beginning of the function writing the code below:

```
Theta1 = initial_theta1.copy()
Theta2 = initial_theta2.copy()
```

I have a solution but I do not understand why value in function effects the outside of the function? That is why I use global variables in Matlab or sometimes in Python. Many thanks.